# How to query relational data in ascending order in strapi?

Tags: strapi

I have this query that works

```
  async find(ctx) {
    let { _start, _limit } = ctx.request.query;
    console.log(ctx.request.query)
    _limit ? 0 : (_limit = 10);
    const entities = await strapi.services["course-series"].find({});
    return entities.map((entity) => {
      // Do I sort them here or in the url query (and how)
      entity.courses = entity.courses.slice(_start, _limit);
      return sanitizeEntity(entity, { model: strapi.models["course-series"] });
    });
  }
```

The idea is that I can load 10 courses from each series at first and then get the next 10...

I just realized that the first 10 I am getting are not the recent ones.

As I commented `// Do I sort them here or in the url query (and how)`

Answer (score 0):

What version of Strapi do you use?
What does this line do `strapi.services["course-series"].find({})`? How did you build this `find` method in the service? What does it do? Does it accept params?

Personally I'd do something like that (assuming you're working with Strapi version > 4:

```js
const entities = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::course-series.course-series', {
  fields: [/* list the course-series fields you want to populate */],
  populate: {
    courses: {
      fields: [/* list the course fields you want to populate */],
      sort: 'createdAt:desc', // You can use id, publishedAt or updatedAt here, depends on your sorting prefrences
      offset: _start,
      limit: _limit // I must admit I haven't tested `offset` and `limit` on the populated related field
    }
  }
})

// ...the rest of your code, if needed
```

Read more about Entity Service API [here](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/entity-service-api.html).

Doing it the way you did it, you will always first retrieve the full list of courses for each `course-series`, and then run costly operations like mapping (the lesser of 2 evils) and above all sorting.

Answer (score 0):

To sort the parent table by child table which is in relation with foreign key

If you are using strapi rest API
you should use

```
sort: childModal.childField:asc
---OR---
sort: childModal.childField:desc
```

E.g:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/products?sort=product_variants.price:desc
```

**In function**

```
const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::article.article', {
  fields: ['name', ],
  sort: { product_variants.price: 'desc' },
});
```